# Brightness and sound not working after downgrading to 18.04 from 20.04 on dell latitude 3420 intel iris graphics

Tags: sound, dell, brightness, backlight

I have received my laptop(dell latitude 3420) pre-installed with ubuntu 20.04, as there is a personal requirement I have removed 20.04 and installed 18.04. After installing 18.04 I found sound is not working(at output it is showing dummy output and input is not being detected) and couldn't find brightness bar.

I have also updated the bios to recent bios provided by vendor. After finding few solutions on the internet I tried changing GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor" in /etc/default/grub. Then I could just see the brightness bar but nothing is changing even though if i use the slider bar. The Kernel version is: Linux 5.4.0-86-generic. And I also noticed this folder **/sys/class/backlight/** is empty.

Although my hardware has **intel iris xe** graphics in the settings details it is showing **llvmpipe (LLVM 10.0.0, 256 bits)**. So, can someone please help me solving the brightness and sound issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I upgrade the kernek to 5.11 ([https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.11/](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v5.11/))
And then https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/06/fix-no-sound-dummy-output-issue-in.html

```
echo "options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

And

```
echo "blacklist snd_soc_skl" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Actually, the last things who don't working is the internal microphone.

Hop it's help

Comment: Hello. You can not down grade the OS. You would have to have installed the lower version. Might you be confused with using a lower version kernel?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1215461)